# IOS: UISearchDisplayController and UITableView.

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've a question about best object to use in my App.

I have a three columns **UITableView** containing a **NSString**, **NSDate**, **double**. I would like to help users **filtering** and make the easiest query. Using **UISearchBar** i can  easily filter the text but i'm not sure. I would like to have **three different** type of search. When date is used for exmaple a **UIDatePicker**.
Which is the best way to proceed? 
Thank you in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
  1)For String  you can use the UISearchBar it will help you to search according to the text entered in it.

  2)For double you can  use the same UISearchBar but you can convert the text which is entered in searchbar as double and proceed filtering with your data.


  3)For NSDate you can give an Option to the user like From Date and To Date so that you can filter and display the records in between the dates
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have to use 3 UISearchBar or implement a custom UISearchDisplayCOntroller?

Comment: one UISearchbar is enough but before enabling the search bar just show a menu which displays the filters available

Comment: One menu with three options: filter1, filter2, filter3. And when I click in one option what can I open?

Comment: if the clicked option is String or double open searchbar and if it is date open datepicker